# How to build a rate app button in Mono Android application

Tags: c#, android, mono, windows-phone, xamarin.android

I'm currently working on porting a game I wrote in C# for Windows Phone over to Android, I'm using MonoGame and building the game with Xamarin Software.

On Windows Phone there are handy functions built into the Windows Phone SDK that allow the application to redirect the user to the MarketPlace so the user can rate the app.

These functions exist under the namespace. `Microsoft.Phone.Tasks`

Calling a `MarketplaceReviewTask` is as simple as the following code, which will redirect the user to the marketplace and allow the user to rate the app that they're using upon clicking the `RateButton`

```
    void RateButton_Selected(object sender, PlayerIndexEventArgs e)
    {
        MarketplaceReviewTask task = new MarketplaceReviewTask();
        task.Show();
    }
```

My question is how do I achieve this effect on an Android Phone? The `Microsoft.Phone.Tasks` Assembly can't be found by Xamarin and I'm a little bit lost as to what to do next. I searched the Internet for problems similar to this and I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure there is no such thing in the android world. Someone might have created some library for it, but i am not aware of any. But you could do something like [this](http://www.androidsnippets.com/prompt-engaged-users-to-rate-your-app-in-the-android-market-appirater) instead. It will prompt your users, after X days or Y launches.

**EDIT:**
After a search on the xamarin blog i found a [guide](http://blog.xamarin.com/get-more-ratings-for-your-ios-and-android-apps/) by James Montemagno. Which will lead you to the [AuditApp in the component store](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/AuditApp)